# A button to modify a cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to place a button in excel sheet to alter a cell content.

for example , I want to fill cell A2 with a date structured as dd/mm/yyyy and once I select the cell and press the button , the cell content (the date) will move forward 1 day.

"1/1/2013

click

2/1/2013"

is such thing possible to be implemented ? can you help ?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `DateAdd()`. Put this code in the button click event. Also change `Sheet1` to the relevant sheetname.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A2").Value = DateAdd("d", 1, .Range("A2").Value)
End With
```

**Syntax**

```
DateAdd(interval, number, date)
```

The interval argument has these settings:

```
yyyy : Year 
q : Quarter 
m : Month 
y : Day of year 
d : Day 
w : Weekday 
ww : Week 
h : Hour 
n : Minute 
s : Second
```

**FOLLOWUP FROM COMMENTS**

> I want to keep the selected cell dynamically , in other words I don't want to be restricted to cell A2 I need to select any cell in the sheet or a complete row or column and apply the action on it.

Try this

```
Dim aCell As Range

If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
    For Each aCell In Selection
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            aCell.Value = DateAdd("d", 1, aCell.Value)
        End With
    Next
End If
```

Comment: dear thanks this worked perfectly but , I want to keep the selected cell dynamically , in other words I don't want to be restricted to cell A2 I need to select any cell in the sheet or a complete row or column and apply the action on it.

Comment: Then use the `Selection` object :)

Comment: .Range("Selection").Value ? sorry I never used VBA before

Comment: Check the code that I updated in the post above. You might have to refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
sub myClick()
  Selection.Value = Selection.value + 1
end sub
```

Comment: Now the macro add in a selected Cell.